# Php is unable to load pdo_mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo, doctrine-orm, php-7

I currently develop a website using Symfony3. 
I want to run command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Unfortunately, I get this php warning :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
```

System : Ubuntu 16.04

php version :

```
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: What do you get when you run this command in the terminal: `php -i | grep pdo_mysql`

Comment: Hi @MohammadZeinEddin thanks for your answer.
I exactly get :
     
     PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
    API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql
    pdo_mysql
    pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: Did you try uninstall then installing the mysql extension?
`sudo apt-get --purge remove php7.0-mysql` then `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql`

Comment: Finally I installed lampp stack with Php 7 and I currently use it.
Now I use it for my developments.

I already don't know what caused these issues, but thank you very much anyway :)

Comment: you should be carefull with sudo apt-get --purge remove php7.0-mysql it will remove phpmydmin too

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, re-installing `php5.6-mysql` fixed it for me.

```
apt-get remove php5.6-mysql
apt-get install php5.6-mysql
```